# How to add images to a ListView in WPF

Tags: c#, wpf, listview, bitmapimage

I want to add images to a ListView. I have converted image to BitmapImage. I have collection of objects that contain Image property which is bind to DataTemplate.

```
<UserControl.Resources>
        <DataTemplate x:Key="ImageCell">
            <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                <Image Source="{Binding DocumentPicture,UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" 
                    Stretch="Fill"  IsEnabled="True" Visibility="Visible"/>
            </StackPanel>
        </DataTemplate>
</UserControl.Resources>

 <ListView Name="lstView" Grid.Column="0" Grid.Row="3"  Margin="5" Height="90" Width="Auto"  
            ItemsSource="{Binding ListDocuments ,UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" ItemTemplate=" 
            {StaticResource ImageCell}" BorderThickness="1" Style="{x:Null}" SelectedItem="{Binding 
             SelectedLstImage}" >
            <ListView.ItemsPanel>
                <ItemsPanelTemplate>
                    <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal" Style="{x:Null}"/>
                </ItemsPanelTemplate>
            </ListView.ItemsPanel>
</ListView>
```

It gives me this output : ( Do not worry about the red background that i set to identify the images in the list. )

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Remove both the instances of ,UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged from your bindings. They're doing nothing.

Remove the stackpanel around the image. That's doing nothing.

Make the listview a listbox. Give the image a width.

Check the names of the things you're binding.

Ensure DocumentPicture is set to something and it's really a public bitmapimage property

```
<UserControl.Resources>
    <DataTemplate x:Key="ImageCell">
            <Image Source="{Binding DocumentPicture}" 
                Width="80"
                Stretch="Fill"  IsEnabled="True" Visibility="Visible"/>
    </DataTemplate>
</UserControl.Resources>

<ListBox Name="lstView" Grid.Column="0" Grid.Row="3"  Margin="5" Height="90" Width="Auto"  
        ItemsSource="{Binding ListDocuments}" ItemTemplate=" 
        {StaticResource ImageCell}" BorderThickness="1" Style="{x:Null}" SelectedItem="{Binding SelectedLstImage}" >
        <ListBox.ItemsPanel>
            <ItemsPanelTemplate>
                <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal" Style="{x:Null}"/>
            </ItemsPanelTemplate>
        </ListBox.ItemsPanel>
</ListBox>
```

See how much closer to working that is.

Answer (score -1):

You could do it programmatically by Iterate throw your List of Images and Instanciate a new Image and add it with 
 `lstView.Items.Add()`

I made a super simple example:

```
<Grid>
    <ListView x:Name="View"></ListView>
    <Button Click="Button_Click" Height="20" Width="20">Button</Button>
</Grid>
```

```
private void Button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            for (int i = 0; i < 20; i++)
            {
                Label lbl = new Label();
                lbl.Content = "Label " + i;
                View.Items.Add(lbl);
            }

        }
```